# fwrite() big filesize corruption, i need scripthelp

Tags: fwrite

I have this kind of script writing a file but i have problems with corrupted files, maybe someone can help me?

```
function savetofile () {
    $dccgettemp = '';
    $dccgettemp = fgets($GLOBALS['dcc_stream'], 512);
    if ($dccgettemp != '') {
        $GLOBALS['dccget'] = $dccgettemp;
        $GLOBALS['currfilesize'] += strlen($dccgettemp);
        fwrite($GLOBALS['handle'], $dccgettemp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only read for up to 511 bytes data from stream and copy the data to the output stream.

So when you need to write all file contents, you must iterate that process until no more data read. Otherwise you can try to increase the rèad buffer size to appropriates size when needed.

```
/* usage:
     1. When used as class method:
         $GLOBALS['currfilesize'] = $this->savetofile($GLOBALS['dcc_stream'], $GLOBALS['handle'], $GLOBALS['currfilesize']);
     Or
     2. When used as regular function:
         $currfilesize = savetofile($dcc_stream, $handle, $currfilesize); 
*/

public function savetofile ($in, $out, $initSize) {
    if ($in && $out) {
        // init output size, set to zero when null
        $size = $initSize ?: 0;

        // reset input file pointer (when needed)
        //rewind($in);

        // gets up to 1024 bytes data from stream
        // iterate all file contents (when needed)
        //while ($dccgettemp = fgets($in, 1025)) {
        if ($dccgettemp = fgets($in, 1025)) {
            // increment output size by buffer size
            $size += strlen($dccgettemp);

            // write to output stream
            fwrite($out, $dccgettemp);

            // forces a write of all buffered output
            // to the resource pointed to by the file handle.
            fflush($out);
        }

        return $size;
    }

    return $initSize;
}
```

You can also use [stream_copy_to_stream()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) function for alternative.

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CtVtdDeH
this is the script, dont know how to change it - can you help?

Comment: You can try to modify the savetofile() function, and invoke the function (modify appropriatelly) as following: $currfilesize = savetofile($dcc_stream, $handle, $currfilesize);

Comment: everytime i change something, the script doesnt work anymore :/ my coding skill is not good enough to know how to change this buffer handle and stream stuff :(

Comment: from the source: $dcc_stream is input stream handle, and $handle is ouput stream handle. you can change buffer size of the input stream by changing the value of the second parameter of fgets() function, which the value is on byte length.

Comment: You can look at the fgets() function on the savetofile() function.